# How to escape from "\." using Java and Selenium

Tags: java, string, selenium, selector, ui-automation

I am working with Java and Selenium in order to write automation e2e tests and I encounter problem.

How I can escape to \ . in Java selenium?

Here is the id of the selector: `email.1` but in order to use it I have to write it like this: `email\.1`. and when I try to create web element ->  `WebElement emailField = driver.findElement(By.id("email\.1")`, I am getting this error **Illegal escape character in string literal**

I understand why I am getting an error, but I can't find a way how to escape it from this. I tried with a different approach from this [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html) but I wasn't able to find a proper solution

Comment: You will need to escape the \ as well, so try using email\\.1.

Comment: I've tired that already, but in that case, my selector is not valid because Java is seeing this as `email\\\.1`

Comment: What's wrong on `driver.findElement(By.id("email.1"));`? Do you gen any exception? Btw better let the id in html be `email1`.

Comment: "I understand why I am getting an error" - do you? You should not escape dot symbol. Dot is just a dot.